# Include sonata menu in custom link with controller view

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have this code in config.yml to add a item to the menu:

```
    # PrestaSonataNavigationBundle
    presta_sonata_navigation:
        menu:
            with_description: false
            items:
                report:
                    roles:
                        - ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
                    children:
                        reportes:
                            route: informe_show
```

This route, "informe_show", it's a route to an action on a controller with a custom view, it isn't display the menu with the  services items.

How can i do to include the sonata menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Sonata administration menu on your front layout, please have a look on this answer: [show sonata admin menu in every page if the admin is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738661/show-sonata-admin-menu-in-every-page-if-the-admin-is-logged-in/20759748#20759748)