# show sonata admin menu in every page if the admin is logged in

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

how can i use the sonata admin menu out side the admin area?

i.e,when a user logged in it will show only the standard menu but when the admin is logged in it will show two menu in every page.

thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

means the admin menu will show above my home main menu??????

and also if the two menu can be one that must be appriciate.thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This navigation bar is in the SonataAdminBundle main layout (Sonata/AdminBundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig).

If you want to use it in your layout, you have to copy/paste the navbar code in your own template and be sure your view can access to required variables (mostly "admin_pool"):

```
return $this->render('YourBundle:View:template.html.twig', array(
    'admin_pool' => $this->get('sonata.admin.pool'),
    ...
```

It this will help you.

Comment: thank you it is the perfect one i already tried this one but for your ans i added the styleseat  block and it worked