# Integrate 3rd party bundles into SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

There is a difficulty while integrating FOSMessageBundle into SonataAdminBundle. I want FOSMessage to be under Sonata's menu. So I made FOSMessage's basic layout to extend standard sonata layout:

`{% extends "::standard_layout.html.twig" %}`

The problem is that sonata menu needs some extra twig variables, which are generated in  its CoreController based controllers:

```
   array(
            'base_template'   => $this->getBaseTemplate(),
            'admin_pool'      => $this->container->get('sonata.admin.pool'),
            'blocks'          => $this->container->getParameter('sonata.admin.configuration.dashboard_blocks')
        );
```

Is there an easy way of providing external (FOSMessageBundle's) templates with these variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an appropriate solution.

In standard Sonata layout replace all menu stuff and put it into isolated template in simple controller:

```
{% render(controller('MyBundle:SonataMenu:index')) %}
```

The controller:

```
namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CoreController;

class SonataMenuController extends CoreController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/sonata_menu", name="sonata_menu")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array(
            'admin_pool' => $this->container->get('sonata.admin.pool'),
        );
    }
}
```

Now standard layout is free for any 3rd party inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Nice solution! If you need to extend the sonata layout you will have to at least at the **admin_pool** variable and pass it to your template:

```
$admin_pool = $this->get('sonata.admin.pool');

return $this->render('ProjectBundle:Controller:page.html.twig', array(
    'admin_pool' => $admin_pool
));
```

Also see:

1. [Sonata Admin - No Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760603/sonata-admin-no-header)
2. [show sonata admin menu in every page if the admin is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738661/show-sonata-admin-menu-in-every-page-if-the-admin-is-logged-in)