# Sonata Admin - No Header

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I extends "SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig and it show me admin theme without header/menu. After the debug code "admin_pool" is not defined I passed from admin_pool from the controller but still not defined.

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I solved header's problem myself using below code

```
$admin_pool = $this->get('sonata.admin.pool');
```

`return $this->render('ProjectBundle:Controller:page.html.twig', 
                array('admin_pool'    => $admin_pool));`